# How to round money value?

Tags: php

I do:

```
echo "Internal studio total costs = ".$sumInternalStudio."<br>";
```

And I get: `Internal studio total costs = 3847401`

If I do

```
$sumInternalStudio = money_format('%.2n', $sumInternalStudio);
echo "Internal studio total costs = ".$sumInternalStudio."<br>"
```

I get

```
Internal studio total costs = € 3.847.401,00
```

But I want to get a round value of `€ 4`

If I do:

```
$sumInternalStudio = round($sumInternalStudio);
$sumInternalStudio = money_format('%.2n', $sumInternalStudio);
echo "Internal studio total costs = ".$sumInternalStudio."<br>";
```

I get

```
Internal studio total costs = € 3.847.401,0
```

And If I do

```
$sumInternalStudio = money_format('%.2n', $sumInternalStudio);
$sumInternalStudio = round($sumInternalStudio);
echo "Internal studio total costs = ".$sumInternalStudio."<br>";
```

I get `Internal studio total costs = 0`

How to round to nearest highest value?

**UPDATE**

I tried

```
$sumInternalStudio = number_format(($sumInternalStudio/100),2); 
$sumInternalStudio = round($sumInternalStudio);
$sumInternalStudio = money_format('%.2n', $sumInternalStudio);
echo "Internal studio total costs = ".$sumInternalStudio."<br>";
```

And I get `Internal studio total costs = € 38,00` but it should be `€ 4`

Comment: you want  round by milions?

Comment: @scaisEdge see the updated question

Comment: @scaisEdge basically the number 3847401 really is 3.847.401 so the round should be 4, I need it to be in euro format

Comment: then you need  the rounded  value as  millions of euros?? please confirm ..

Comment: 3847401 really is 3847401. while 3,8 rounded up is 4.0.

Comment: @scaisEdge yes I suppose, I mean I will always get a full number like 3847401, I will need to add decimals to it to find out if it is a billion, a million or hundreds etc

Comment: @Butuzov yes see my above comment

Comment: Change the precision of round before you convert to money https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: @TimMorton which precision should I use then?

Comment: -6 or something. with PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP I guess...

Comment: @Butuzov ok I will try but why did you say "you guess", what might not work? I need a general solution as i don't know what number to work on I will get

Comment: Suppose your number is `a` so the formula is: `round(a / (10 ** int(log10(a))), 0)`. If it works tell me to post it as the answer.

Comment: @Butuzov this gives me zero       $sumInternalStudio = round($sumInternalStudio, -6, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
      echo $sumInternalStudio;

Comment: you are lazy. `round($n, -6, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);`

Comment: @Butuzov I had tried it as you suggested, why lazy? that gives me zero

Comment: @MaskedMan this breaks it $sumInternalStudio = round($sumInternalStudio / (10 ** int(log10($sumInternalStudio))), 0);

Comment: @rob.m `bash#php -r 'echo round(3847401, -6, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);'`

Comment: @Butuzov ok yes works, sorry had left the line where I was setting the number format. It works and gives me 4. Now One question in regards, will -6 and PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP would work if I'd have 12300 or 110 or 1200 ?

Comment: also that it is now giving € 4.000.000,00 how about € 4?

Comment: why a down vote? Explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
$formattedSum = '€ '.number_format(3847401, 2, ',', '.');
```

> € 3.84

or [round](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php):

```
$formattedSum = '€ '.round(3847401 / 1000000);
```

> € 4

Comment: echo "Internal studio total costs = € ".number_format($sumInternalStudio, 2, ',', '.')."<br>"; gives Internal studio total costs = € 3.847.401,00

Comment: will this works if we'd have 120 or 12300 or 12323333?

Comment: @rob.m Yes, you can follow the link to the documentation, to learn more about the function.

Comment: what if we'd want to add M if it is a million or a B ? € 4M